# How to change foreach to lambda with Parallel Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have following method

```
private Set<Chapter> chapters;
public long getCount() {
    long count = 0;
    for (Chapter chapter : chapters) count += chapter.getCount();
    return count;
}
```

and I want to improve this code using Java 8 features such as streams and lambda, but I can not change the external variables into lambda, so I tried to cheat, but it was an awful solution.

```
public long getCount() {
    final long[] count = {0};
    chapters.parallelStream().forEach(chapter -> count[0] += chapter.getCount());
    return count[0];
}
```

Can you help me with that - or provide some useful link to me.
Sorry if it's a duplicate.

Comment: That’s not an “awful solution” as concurrent access to an array element is *entirely broken*. So it’s no solution at all. But you have already [found the correct solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37249194/2711488)…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't matter anymore, I'm already find single row solution with `mapToLong()`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

```
public long getCount() {
    return chapters.parallelStream().mapToLong(Chapter::getCount).sum();
}
```

Comment: Note that using `parallelStream` can significantly _hurt_ performance if there aren't a _huge_ number of chapters.